# How to run (not install) apk file from adb command line

Tags: command-line-interface, apk

I already installed an app using the "adb install " command, and could locate the corresponding .apk and .so files in the android device. I can see the app installed properly on the GUI, and I can run it from the GUI by clicking on the icon. When I kill the process inside the adb, the app is successfully closed.

My question is whether it is possible to execute the app through command line? I already tried "./" but it gave me errors. Also, this question is not specific to the particular app, but in general I wanted to know whether we can run any apk file via CLI.

I searched on many forums but they all gave procedures to "install" an app but not how to "run" it.

Comment: AFAIK, the APK requires either an emulator or Android device to run on, or there's no OS for it. There's no such thing as "running it from the command-line".

Comment: I think he means a command to run the apk in the device/emulator.

Answer (score 0):

**adb -d shell "am start -a** android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.kuyniamaxu/.KuyActivity"